# How __promise in ARM-compiler improves the efficiency

Tags: c, performance, arm

I read [here](https://www.arm.com/files/pdf/AT_-_Better_C_Code_for_ARM_Devices.pdf) (page 14) that one way to improve the code efficiency for ARM-devices would be to use ARM_compiler specific keywords like `__promise`and the folowing sample code is mentioned:

```
void f(int *x, int n)
{
  int i;
  __promise((n > 0) && ((n & 7) == 0));   /* My Question: How this line improves efficiency */ 

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    x[i]++;
  }
}
```

But I don't undrestand how this extra information (the loop index is positive and divisable by 8) improves the efficiency!

could anybody please explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
__promise((n > 0) && ((n & 7) == 0));
```

The binary representation of `7` is `0b111`. This tells you that the last 3 bits of `n` will always be zero. Therefore `n` must be a multiple of `8`. Furtermore `n` will also be greater than `0`.

You thus promise the compiler, that it can safely unroll your loop into blocks of `8`, and that it will do at least one iteration.

The compiler *could* therefore choose to rewrite your code as:

```
int i = 0;
do
  {
    x[i+0]++;
    x[i+1]++;
    x[i+2]++;
    x[i+3]++;
    x[i+4]++;
    x[i+5]++;
    x[i+6]++;
    x[i+7]++;
  } while ((i+=8) != n);
```

Which will skip a bunch of comparisons.

NEONs `VADD` instruction will even allow you to optimize this even further: `vaddq_s32` would allow you to add the vector (1,1,1,1) to groups of four elements of your array at once. So your compiler could replace that block with two vadd instructions (if it feels you could benefit from that).

Comment: I got it, thanx. wuld you please give me any reference about such ARM-specific keywords like `__pur`, `__promise` etc.

Comment: Officially, that would be the compiler manual: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491g/CJACHIDG.html